# Error 1064 sql phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, syntax, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

This is my sql query:

```
CREATE TABLE estados (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    paridad int NOT NULL
);
```

and it keeps telling me:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>       nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
>       paridad int NOT NULL

I don't know why is this, I am using 10.1.10-MariaDB. I don't know why I have syntax error, and if this has to do with the versions.

Comment: I believe `IDENTITY` is not supported b MySQL. Try its counterpart, `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IDENTITY` is for SQL Server. You should use `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead:

```
CREATE TABLE estados (
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    paridad int NOT NULL
);
```